# Multiprocessing reuse Processors

Tags: python, multiprocess

I intend to use multiprocessing to speed up my image pipeline:
Therefore, I compare a process in sequence with a multiprocessing step.
Actually the sequence process is faster than the multiprocessing step.
Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it is to cost intense to create each time a new processor which is why I want to reuse the processor. On the other hand I could have ran into shared data. But I'm not an expert.  Thanks everyone in advance!

My Code:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import asyncio
import glob
import cv2
import time
q_img = multiprocessing.Queue()

def readImg(images,numbers,q_img,q_feature_1,q_feature_2):
    start =  time.time() 
    cnt = 0
    for n in numbers:
        #print("Start process",n)
        n = cv2.imread(images[n],0)
        q_img.put(n)
        if cnt == 20:
            prozess2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = calc_feature1, args =(q_img,q_feature_1))
            prozess2.start() 
            cnt = 0
        cnt += 1
        time.sleep(0.001)
    end =  time.time()   
    print("PROCESS 1 finnished",end - start) 

def calc_feature1(q_img,q_feature):
    while q_img.empty() is False:
        img = q_img.get()
        #print("ThreshCalculation")
        #Start Barcode detection
        sq_n = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        sq_n = cv2.threshold(img,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        sq_n = cv2.threshold(img,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        q_feature.put(sq_n)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = np.arange(0,200)
    images = glob.glob("InputSimulation\*"+".jpg")
    start = time.time()
    Thresh = []
    for img_path in images:
        img = cv2.imread(img_path,0)
        Thresh.append(cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY))
        Thresh.append(cv2.threshold(img,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY))
        Thresh.append(cv2.threshold(img,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY))
        time.sleep(0.001)
    end = time.time()
    print("Sequencial",end - start)  

    q_img = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q_feature_1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q_feature_2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    prozess1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = readImg, args =(images,numbers,q_img,q_feature_1,q_feature_2))
    prozess1.start()
    if (q_img.empty()):
        prozess1.join() 

    idx = 0
    while q_feature_1.empty() is False:
        root = (q_feature_1.get())
        print("Results",idx)
        idx +=1
```

**RESULT:**

*Sequencial 6.204113006591797
PROCESS 1 finnished 7.102877140045166*

Second Try: This time i want to split up my data into 50 image chunks and start a processor if 50 images have been read

```
    import os, sys, errno
import re
import argparse
from time import time
import multiprocessing
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
def computeFeatures(input_chunk, chunk_num):
    thresholded_chunk = []
    print("Processing Chunk,",chunk_num)
    for img in input_chunk:
        thresholded_chunk.append(cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV))    
    return (thresholded_chunk, chunk_num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time()
    # Handle command line options
    numProcessors = 8

    # Start my pool
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(numProcessors)

    # Build task list
    tasks = []
    image_list= []
    img_idx = 0
    image_pathes = glob.glob("InputSimulation\*.jpg")
    image_Q = multiprocessing.Queue(len(image_pathes))
    results = []
    while img_idx < len(image_pathes):
        print("InsterImageNumber",img_idx)
        image_list.append(cv2.imread(image_pathes[img_idx],0))
        if img_idx % 50 == 0 and img_idx != 0:
            print("SetUpChunk",(img_idx / 50))
            img_chunk = image_list[int((img_idx / 50)-1):int((img_idx / 50))].copy()
            tasks.append( (img_chunk, (img_idx / 50),))
            print("Calculate results")
            results.append([pool.apply_async( computeFeatures, t ) for t in tasks])
        img_idx +=1
        # Run tasks    #Flatten list before print
    end = time()
    print("DURATION",end - start)
    # Process results
    print(results)
    for processor in results:
        for result in processor:
             print(result)
             (Image, chunk) = result.get()
             cv2.imshow("Thresh",Image)
             print("Result: plot %d written to %s" % (Image, chunk) )
```

Comment: passing OpenCV image object between processing needs a lot of work, very inefficient, you could try to do image loading and following calculation with one process and measure again.

Comment: Done that have no speed up because of shared data due to the image and the processor parallelization afford as far as I could interprete the speed of the program. Maybe my code has done something unexpected. Would you mind to give an example or a tutorial where this is performed? Greetings

Comment: oh then you only have one worker process, try launching more, match cores number in your machine, you could use `Pool`

Comment: Also done that ^^ plus I splited the image data of 200 to 50 images for each worker to avoid communication overhead with less worse results but still not better than when I use sequences :). I also tried async. In my opinion I might have problems to schedule the tasks such that no data is shared and afterwards I have to combine the data. The reason for that is my process pipeline. I have to take an image and compute its features. This must be done for 200 images a 2048x2480 px each. The problem is that I dont have found an example where I can put in an image array and process in parallel.

Comment: could you update your question with your new code?

Comment: I have overwritten my old code with this one since I haven't seen the desired speed up. Maybe I'm into this topic next week. This week I scheduled network communication for this week because of avoiding getting stuck into one part of the task :-/